# How to download image from node js and convert it to binary

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I have an image at some url, for example 'http://91.123.58.169:322/snapshot.cgi?user=admin&pwd=123456'. It's an IP-camera's current frame.

I want to download this image to node.js server, convert it to binary and send via socket.io

What is the correct way to solve my problem?

Comment: You should revert the post and add the completed code as answer so others can learn from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i wrote code by myself and it works.
So, we have IP-camera image frame.
We get it by http-request module, then save it to filesystem and then send encoded to base64 image to client via socket.io

```
var httpRequest = require('http-request');
    socket.on('camera', function(data) {
            var options = { url: 'http://192.168.1.178:80/snapshot.cgi?user=admin&amp;pwd=123456' };
            httpRequest.get(options, __dirname + '/camera.jpg', function(error, result) {
                if (error) {
                    console.error(error);
                } else {
                    fs.readFile(__dirname + '/camera.jpg', function(err, buf) {
                        socket.emit('camera', { image: true, buffer: buf.toString('base64') });
                    });
                }
            });
        });
```

Meanwhile on client:

```
socket.on('camera', function(data) {
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + data.buffer;

    var img = $("<img />").attr('src', image.src);
    $("#cameraDiv").empty();
    $("#cameraDiv").append(img);
    img.addClass("img-rounded img-responsive");
    img.css("width", "400px");
    img.css("height", "300px");
    img.css("margin-left", "auto");
    img.css("margin-right", "auto");
});
```